# Binary serialize/deserialize via sockets TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization, binary, deserialization

I have 3 projects, first is the client, second is the server and the last one is the BroadcastMessage:

In the client have this code to serialize and object (this = BroadcastMessage):

```
public MemoryStream SerializeObject()
{
     MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

     BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

     formatter.Serialize(stream, this);

     return stream;
}
```

Then, I convert this stream into byte[] and send via sockets to the Server, there, I deserialize with this:

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
Stream str = new MemoryStream(inMessage);
BroadcastMessage m = (BroadcastMessage) formatter.Deserialize(str);
```

The communication between client and server is correct, I receive the complete stream, but when I try to deserialize, simply doesn´t work, giving me an TargetInvocationException, cause is trying to find the project where the object (BroadcastMessage) was serialized. If I add this project to the Server the deserialization works without problems, but I cannot add a project of everyclass that uses this "BroadcastMessage".

Any suggestions? Is there a way to indicate the correct namespace when I serialize? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Ok, the problem was caused because I was subscribed in a event of the class, getting out the listening of the event and works perfectly, Thanks all for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to reference the whole project. An assembly with the specific types is sufficient. Hence you should put all types that need to be (de)serialized in their own assembly and reference this from both projects.

You need to define those types anyway, and such you'll get rid of putting the same code twice in your projects (DRY principle).

Comment: Hi @JeffRSon

I think I don´t understand you at all,

In one hand I have the Server, in other hand I have the Client,

To do the communication between them, I use another one, BroadcastMessage. 
The server references to the BroadcastMessage and the client.
The client references, to the BroadcastMessage.

Comment: Cont..

The scenario is: the client is implemented by X number of projects, for example, the project A has implemented the Client, then when I send a BroadcastMessage to the server from the project A, the exception rise in the server saying that he cannot find the project A, if I add the reference in the Server of the project A, (dll or the whole project, doesn´t matter) then works.
But Broadcast stuff will be implemented in at least 10 projects, and add all the references into the Server...I don´t know, have to be other way

Comment: The problem is if you copy sources of `BroadcastMessage` it's all different types for the serializer - you need to make sure that it's always the same type. So you should define all shared types (like `BroadcastMessage`) in one project (one assembly) that can be referenced from client(s) and server. Such you don't have `BroadcastMessage` defined in 10 projects, but only one (that is used everywhere).

Comment: So, if I understand you, what you mean is make a new project with all the references that references to the BroadcastMessage, then uses this project to references in all of them, and the Server, right?

I will try, and let you know, and if is working mark like solve, thanks for your time. =D

Comment: I tried everything and there is no way to make this works -.-.

Any other suggestion?

Comment: Yeah, finally, was a "noob" mistake, the BroadcastMessage has an event and I was subscribe before the serialize, so when the server tried to deserialize rise the exception cause cannot find the subscriptors =D